# Impossible to get border's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events

My code:

```
<head>
<style> 
#doit{
    border:5px solid blue;
    color:white
}
</style>
</head>

<button id="doit">Click me </button>
<script> 
$('#doit').click(function(event){
      console.log ($(event.currentTarget).css('border'));
      var x=window.getComputedStyle(event.currentTarget);
      console.log(x.border);
      });
   </script>
```

It is just impossible to get the border value in **Mozilla and IE11**. *Chrome works fine*!! To get things more strange if I change `border` with `color` everything is fine. How may I solve this problem? Neither `borderWidth` works... However, I want to get border's value. Please, help!

Comment: why are you using e.currentTarget instead of this?

Comment: These browsers do not support the shorthand CSS. You need to be specific.